# Encoding Conversion with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

Trying to do a Latin1 to UTF-8 conversion for WordPress, had no luck with the tutorial posted in the Codex.  I came up with this to check encoding and convert.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
if(!mb_check_encoding($row['post_content'], 'UTF-8')) {

    $row = mb_convert_encoding($row['post_content'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

    if(!mb_check_encoding($row['post_content'], 'UTF-8')) {
        echo 'Can\'t Be Converted<br/>';    
    }
    else {
        echo '<br/>'.$row.'<br/><br/>';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'UTF-8<br/>';
}
}
```

This works... sorta.  I'm not getting any rows that can't converted but I did notice that  PanamÃ¡ becomes Panam

Am I missing a step? Or am I doing this all wrong?

## **UPDATE**

The data stored within the database is corrupt(Ã¡ characters are stored). So its looking  more like a find and replace job than a conversion.  I haven't found any great solutions so far for doing this automagically.

Comment: Can we rule out the possibility that it's just the browser not interpreting the HTML as UTF-8? Also, what is the table encoding? And what is the mysql connection encoding (see `SET NAMES`)?

Comment: Yes, I took a look through the MySQL dump to make sure.

Comment: Have you tried passing the source charset to `mb_convert_encoding()` ?

Comment: Database is UTF8 connection is utf8_general_ci

Comment: Make sure you have this in the `<head>` of your HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @Mark that didn't quite do it

Comment: Are you really sure that the original `$row['post_content']` is in ISO-8859-1? Your code seems to assume it, but does not check.

Comment: @Mark Is there a way I can check for sure?

Comment: There is no way to determine for sure what encoding a particular byte steam is in. You can only guess.

Comment: Is this your actual code? On line 4, `$row` becomes a string, but you're still treating it as an array on line 6!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

Further more you can set your mysql connection to utf8 this way:

```
mysql_set_charset  ('utf8',$this->getConnection());
```

$this->getConnection in my code returns the variable which was returned by

```
mysql_connect(MYSQL_SERVER,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the PHP documentation for `mb_convert_encoding`:

`string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding ] )`

Your code is attempting to convert **to** ISO-8859-1 **from** UTF-8!

Comment: I really wish it was that simple! Unfortunately that didn't end up working either.

Comment: Is this the Codex article you're referring to? http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets If you follow it correctly, doesn't look as if a PHP script should be necessary at all....

Comment: @Mark Yes.  The problem I was having was when I would use the "3-Step" some stray character would cut out the remainder of a post.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is over my head. I've always used latin1 for my database and its connections, and used UTF-8 on all my HTML pages. Never had a bit of trouble with that. For your conversion, you might try using mysqldump to export the data, interpreting it as a certain encoding (using `--default-character-set`), then importing it again, using the same or a different character set. Of course there may be a good reason why they don't use that technique in the Codex....

Comment: @Mark I really appreciate the effort, I'll give that a try to see how it goes.

Comment: I forgot to mention: the mysql command (for importing) also has the `--default-character-set` option.